# Azure.Mobile in app and AppCenter in framework triggers a "Cannot register two managed types"

Tags: c#, azure, xamarin.ios

I've been having conflicts with `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile` and `Microsoft.AppCenter` in a Xamarin iOS project.

I'm creating a framework that will be released as a nuget, in that framework I reference `AppCenter`. The app where I'm testing my nuget has a reference to `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile`, which references the same `Microsoft.AppCenter` nuget triggering the following error:

Project/iOS/MTOUCH: Error MT4116: Could not register the assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.iOS.Bindings': error MT4118: Cannot register two managed types ('Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.iOS.Bindings.MSCustomProperties, Microsoft.Azure.Mobile.iOS.Bindings' and 'Microsoft.AppCenter.iOS.Bindings.MSCustomProperties, Microsoft.AppCenter.iOS.Bindings') with the same native name ('MSCustomProperties'). (MT4116)(Project.iOS)

I tried the following solutions with no success:

1: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/54126/#Comment_54126

2: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/4721

Would love some help :)

Comment: Are the two nuget packages both have the latest version?

Comment: The `Azure.Mobile` nuget has the latest version but the `AppCenter` nuget doesn't because of compatibility issues.

Comment: I would recommend you to use the latest version including the Xamarin.iOS. Also try to clean/rebuild your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the `Microsoft.Azure.Mobile` it's an old package no longer being supported and is using the `AppCenter` services, I removed that package and just added the most recent package from `AppCenter` which uses the same services.